# How to iteratively add seconds to a datetime

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to iteratively increase time by 3 seconds and store the results in the following format:

```
1/2/2015 6:00:00 AM
1/2/2015 6:00:03 AM
1/2/2015 6:00:06 AM
1/2/2015 6:00:09 AM
```

This is how I started implementing it:

```
SimpleDateFormat _sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/YYYY HH:mm:ss AM");
_time = "1/2/2015 6:00:00 AM";
Date date;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
try {
            date = _sdf.parse(_time);
            Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            // how to add seconds ???
            // System.out.println(...);
} catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
```

For the output:

```
String formattedDate = _sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

Another way is the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
    String _time = "1/2/2015 6:00:09 AM";
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(_time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y H:m:s a"));
    dt = dt.plusSeconds(3); // since LocalDateTime is an immutable date-time object
    System.out.println(dt.toString());
```